# Automation Runbook not able to set default subscription on run

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell, azure-automation

Cloned a sample non classic runbook and attempted to set the subscription as default. This gives me following error:

```
Select-AzureSubscription : The subscription name {nameofsubscription} doesn't exist.
Parameter name: name
At step1_validate:18 char:18
+ 
+ CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Select-AzureSubscription], ArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Profile.SelectAzureSubscriptionCommand
```

How would it be possible to select or set a particular subscription as default? Below approaches throw above mentioned error:

> Approach 1

```
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $defaultSubscriptionname –Default 

Get-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId 123XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX96eXX58 | Select-AzureSubscription
```

> Approach 2

```
$subscriptionId = (Get-AzureRmSubscription | Out-GridView -Title 'Select Azure Subscription:' -PassThru).Id
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
```

**Trying :** To get particular resource name and make configurational changes, or to use Get-Azurewebsite cmdlet, setting a subscription appears mandatory.

Note: Hoping adding Service Principal used in the automation account to default subscription might help, I also tried to add the ApplicationId to Access control of Subscription as contributor. Though my Runbook being mentioned here and WebApps are in same subscription. Reference: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/knightly/2017/05/26/using-azure-automation-with-multiple-subscriptions/#comment-1555 ( Scenario for me is both are in same subscription )

EDIT: Pasting Code

```
<# 
This PowerShell script was automatically converted to PowerShell Workflow so it can be run as a runbook.
Specific changes that have been made are marked with a comment starting with “Converter:”
#>
<#
.DESCRIPTION
    To watch php version old in app, and if found turn it off and apply 5.6 

.NOTES
    AUTHOR: HBala
    LASTEDIT: Jan 04, 2018
#>

workflow step1_validate {

# Converter: Wrapping initial script in an InlineScript activity, and passing any parameters for use within the InlineScript
# Converter: If you want this InlineScript to execute on another host rather than the Automation worker, simply add some combination of -PSComputerName, -PSCredential, -PSConnectionURI, or other workflow common parameters (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj129719.aspx) as parameters of the InlineScript
inlineScript {
    $connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
    $myResourceGroupName = "DevstorageRG"
    $defaultSubscriptionname = "StandardDevStaging"
    $newPhpVersion = "5.6"

    try
    {
        # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
        $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

        "Logging in to Azure..."
        Add-AzureRmAccount `
    -ServicePrincipal `
    -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
    -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
    -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
    }
    catch {
        if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
        {
            $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
            throw $ErrorMessage
        } else{
            Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
            throw $_.Exception
        }
    }

    #Get all ARM resources from all resource groups
    $ResourceGroups = Get-AzureRmResourceGroup 

    foreach ($ResourceGroup in $ResourceGroups)
    {    
        Write-Output ("Showing resources in resource group " + $ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName)

        if( $ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName -eq $myResourceGroupName ){
            $Resources = Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupNameContains $ResourceGroup.ResourceGroupName | Select ResourceName, ResourceType
            ForEach ($Resource in $Resources)
            {

                    Write-Output ($Resource.ResourceName + " of type " +  $Resource.ResourceType)

                    Write-Output ($Resource.ResourceName + " of type " +  $Resource.ResourceType)

                    #Switch-AzureMode AzureServiceManagement
                    # Local powershell connects and works perfect with what I wanted to achieve.
                    # On Automation account, Runbook migration, it threw Azure subcription not set error for Set-AzureWebsite. 
                    # so remove rest of the code and focused on few options to get the default as below
                    # which led me to post the thread.
                    # 
                    # Approach 1
                    Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $defaultSubscriptionname –Default 
                    Get-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId 1238XXXXXXXXXXXe5XXXX8 | Select-AzureSubscription

                    # Approach 2
                    $subscriptionId = (Get-AzureRmSubscription | Out-GridView -Title 'Select Azure Subscription:' -PassThru).Id
                    Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

                    Write-Output ( "==============Subscription ID :===========")
                    Write-Output( $subscriptionId)

                    # Wants to update config / php version parameters.
                    Set-AzureWebsite -Name $Resource.ResourceName -HttpLoggingEnabled 1 -PhpVersion 5.6

                    # Had tried this as well which was suggested by Jason. But appears not working.. 
                    # looks like I have messed it up.                        
                    Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $myResourceGroupName -Name $Resource.ResourceName
                    Set-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $myResourceGroupName -Name $Resource.ResourceName -HttpLoggingEnabled 1 -PhpVersion 5.6
            }
        }
        Write-Output ("Completed!@Line83")
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: What deployment model are you using? ARM or Classic? What is your role assignment in the subscription?

Comment: @Ramana ARM and is co-admin role in all subscriptions. The service principal is added to subscription as 'Contributor'.

Answer (score 1):

> Hoping adding the serviceprincipal type addition for the
>   automationaccount to default subscription might help

You are right, we can use Azure automation account **connections** to select subscription.

For example, we can new a connection and the type is `Azure service principal`.

like this:
[image]

[image]

Then use this powershell script to select the connection:

```
$connectionName = "jason"
try
{
    # Get the connection "jason "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
       -ServicePrincipal `
       -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
       -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
       -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
   if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
   {
      $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
      throw $ErrorMessage
  } else{
      Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
      throw $_.Exception
  }
}
```

In this way, we can use connection to select subscription.

By the way, we can follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal) to create service principal.

Comment: Thanks @Jason. Yes, This part works, and I was using 'AzureRunAsConnection' resource but my challenge is post this.. both approach 1 or 2 after try/catch block is not able to get a subscription set (1/2)

Comment: The challenge is post the try/catch block, I attempted to get webapp configurations and make some changes. It says, no subscription selected. If I attempt to enable a subscription default, it gives me above error as in main post. I am not sure how to set a subscription for using cmdlets like 'Get-Azurewebsite' or 'Set-Azurewebsite'. :(

Comment: @HBala Use `AzureRunAsConnection` connection, we should use `Get-AzureRmWebApp` to set it, use ARM PowerShell command. For now, classic web site move to ARM, we should use ARM command to do it.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Hi Jason, I agree with your shared points, is useful. If in your code,  how could I set the default subscription post that catch block in your code and update a webapp configuration data like php5.5 to php 5.6 or so? Attempting to update calls no default subscription set as in my main post and so not able to retrieve/update webapp configurations? Any suggestions would be great help.

Comment: @HBala We should use ARM powershell command to do it, we just should add powershell script in that runbook. when we use that connection, we will use that subscription as default subscription.

Comment: @HBala we can use this command to change PHP version `Set-AzureRmWebApp -PhpVersion <string>`.

Comment: Yes! I tried that also Get-AzureRmWebApp and Set-AzureRmWebApp but it also doesnt seem to work. Gives me Set-AzureRmWebApp : The term 'Set-AzureRmWebApp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
again.

Comment: I used Get-AzureRmResourceGroup to get all RG and then for looped it filtering on RG's interested in to set their version. but inside for loop not able to get any of the cmdlets to work. :( but am definitely able to write-out the name of the apps in each RG.. just that not able to invoke any other cmdlet for any desired action.. :(

Comment: @HBala could you share your powershell script?

Comment: Sure, I have pasted the code for your reference as update to my thread. Thanks for the patience.

Comment: @HBala we can't switch Azure mode to ASM in that powershell, we should use ARM command to change website config, can't use ASM command to change it.